# create new project from an existing one in Eclipse, yet another question on the subject

Tags: android, project, manifest

First of all I did search on Stackoverflow, Google and everywhere I could think of. Still I have no solution for the problem. So sorry if this is question number 1000 on the same subject, but none of the answers worked for me :/

I'm trying to create a new project from an existing one in Eclipse. Simple as that. I want to check out the example projects from the book "Unlocking Android", like [this one](http://xsys-clan.se/ch1.zip) and [this one](http://xsys-clan.se/ch2.zip).

Message from the console in Eclipse:
"com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read C:\Users\Fredrik\workspace\test\ch3\AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Fredrik\workspace\test\ch3\AndroidManifest.xml"

I have been able to open other existing projects, like LunarLander and JetBoy, and run them in the Android emulator.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong..?
thx...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the target version of the AVD

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't seem to do it unfortunately.. Or maybe I misinterpreted your advice. Could you be even more specific for a poor noob? ...:)